When a Statement has Two Footnotes---How to Add a Comma?
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
This is a sentence.\footnote{\lipsum[31]}
This is a sentence.\footnote{\lipsum[31]}\footnote{\lipsum[32]}
\end{document}

which produces

QUESTION: How may I add a comma to separate footnotes 2 and 3 so that it does not look like, in this case, the footnotemark 23? Is there a better way to apply two footnotes to the same statement  other than \footnote{}\footnote?
Thank you.
